# How i can open browser onPostExecute

Tags: java, android

Here is the code

```
Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(this.redirectUrl+"?username="+getValue(loginString)+"&password="+getValue(pwdString)));
startActivity(browserIntent);
```

I have this error :

```
10-17 15:30:35.288    5467-5467/com.example.android.navigationdrawerexample W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40cd7930)
10-17 15:30:35.298    5467-5467/com.example.android.navigationdrawerexample E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment PlanetFragment{41b91f78} not attached to Activity
```

at this line :

```
startActivity(browserIntent);
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10919240/fragment-myfragment-not-attached-to-activity) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10919240/fragment-myfragment-not-attached-to-activity/10941410#10941410) DOESN'T work for me.
What i can do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you just call getActivity() from Fragment and then call startActivity() like getActivity().startActivity(intent);

Answer (score 0):

From the exception, it looks like you're calling this method on a Fragment that is not (yet?) attached to an Activity. From the source of the `Fragment` class:

```
public void startActivity(Intent intent, Bundle options) {
    if (mActivity == null) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Fragment " + this + " not attached to Activity");
    }
    ...
```

To fix this, just change the place where this method is called, i.e. after `onAttach()` and before `onDetach()`.