# Android error getString from resource

Tags: android, xml, string

I'm trying to get the strings from strings.xml file, but I get this error:`java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment Ric_fragment{3975f30e} not attached to Activity`

```
public class Ricerca_fragment_menu extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment {

private ListView lista;

String[] itemname ={
        getResources().getString(R.string.ric_e),
        getResources().getString(R.string.ric_u),
        getResources().getString(R.string.ric_p),
        getResources().getString(R.string.txt_c),
        getResources().getString(R.string.ric_c),
        getResources().getString(R.string.ben)
};
...
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Fragment MyFragment not attached to Activity](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10919240/fragment-myfragment-not-attached-to-activity)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't call `getResources()` before `onCreate`, because the Fragment is not completely created. You should modify your code like this:

```
String[] itemname;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    itemname = new String[] {
            getResources().getString(R.string.hello_blank_fragment),
            getResources().getString(R.string.hello_blank_fragment),
            getResources().getString(R.string.hello_blank_fragment),
            getResources().getString(R.string.hello_blank_fragment),
            getResources().getString(R.string.hello_blank_fragment),
            getResources().getString(R.string.hello_blank_fragment)
    };
}
```