# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment not attached to Activity issue in android

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I am facing strange issue during call of my activity with Fragment usage. I am getting error like,

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment ScoreFragment{ee2b833
>   id=0x7f0e0198} not attached to Activity

On line 146. My Fragment code which have error is line like below

```
if(mPageFlag.equalsIgnoreCase(getString(R.string.winners))){
```

And My full code for same is below,

```
 @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
  if (getArguments() != null) {
    mPageFlag = getArguments().getString(ARG_PAGE_FLAG); 
  } 
}

@Override
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
    super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
    if(isVisibleToUser && !mIsPageLoaded){
        mContext = getActivity();
        mIsPageLoaded = true;
        if(mPageFlag.equalsIgnoreCase(getString(R.string.winners))){
            new getcontestscorewinners(mContext).execute();
        }else{ //

            new getcontestscorewinnersNew(mContext).execute();
        }
    }
}


public class getcontestscorewinners extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    boolean response = false;

    private Context mContext;

    public getcontestscorewinners(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {

        progress = ProgressDialog.show(mContext, "Processing...",
                "Please wait....");
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        NetworkTask.getContestScoreWinners(winnerHandler);


        return "";

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {


    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {

    }
}
```

Let me know if someone can help me for get out of it. Thanks.

Comment: `setUserVisibleHint` is in Activity or in Fragment ? and where adding `mPageFlag` to Activity

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK is in Fragment and mPageFlag I am adding it on create like public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mPageFlag = getArguments().getString(ARG_PAGE_FLAG);
        }
    }

Comment: Your `Context` `mContext` is null.

Comment: @KNeerajLal what should I use then as per You ?

Comment: possible duplicate of :  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10919240/fragment-myfragment-not-attached-to-activity

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try using [`isAdded():`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#isAdded())

> Return true if the fragment is currently added to its activity.

So your code should be like this :

```
if(isAdded() && mPageFlag.equalsIgnoreCase(getString(R.string.winners))){
```

Comment: This is the currect Answer. Thanks @shadygoneinsane