# Get fragment Edit Text value from parent activity android

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a `DialogFragment` on an `Activity` class. This fragment has an `EditText` field and all I want to do is check if the field has less than 3 digits on the input then show a toast message. App keeps crashing and I can't even see what exception it is throwing me in the LogCat/Stacktrace.

Activity Class:

```
public class ParentActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
    public boolean getTextCodeLength(){
        EditText editTextfield = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.textFieldName);
        if(editTextfield.length() < 4)
        {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Fragment Class:

```
public class EnterTextFragment extends DialogFragment {
    public void onDialogOkClick(DialogInterface dialog) {
     try {
            15. boolean result = ((ParentActivity) getActivity()).getTextCodeLength();
            if (result == false) {
                Toast.makeText(myContext, "Code needs to be longer than 4 digits", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Log.e("YOUR_APP_LOG_TAG", "I got an error", ex);
        }

    //Perform some other functions
    }
}
```

Whenever it hits the line marked with number `15` - it keeps crashing and I don't even get what's causing the error because I am unable to see any exceptions in the LogCat as mentioned. Some help would great be appreciated.

More Context:
The toast is for testing purposes. Ideally I want to let the user stay on the fragment if their input is less than 4 digits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why you don't handle `getTextCodeLength()` inside the fragment? It's wrong to define it inside the activity since it uses fields from fragment and the result is used only inside the fragment. I would is to keep a reference of the field inside the fragment (finding a view in the hierarchy is costly and it shouldn't be done each time when you press the button). So, declare a `EditText` in the fragment:

```
private EditText editText;
```

Override `onCreateView` to get a reference of the field:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View contentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_fragment_layout, container, false);
    editText = contentView.findViewById(R.id.textFieldName);
    return contentView;
}
```

Then delete the `getTextCodeLength` from the activity(also, maybe rename this method since the current name is misleading) and move it inside the fragment:

```
public boolean getTextCodeLength(){
    if(editText.length() < 4)
    {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Now everything should work smoothly without any crashes.

Answer (score 0):

Move this code to onCreate method of activity:

```
mEditTextfield = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.textFieldName);
```

Add field to your activity class:

```
private EditText mEditTextfield;
```

Modify your method:

```
public boolean getTextCodeLength(){
        if(mEditTextfield.length() < LIMIT)
        {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
}
```

Also check if fragment is attached to activity in onDialogOkClick().

Comment: I implemented your changes and included a check: ` if(((ConnectingActivity) getActivity()) == null)` and it crashes again on this line

Comment: Also had a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10919240/fragment-myfragment-not-attached-to-activity but no luck

Comment: How do you show dialog? 
It can be CEE (class cast exception). So you should check if getActivity instanceOf ConnectingActivity

Comment: `private ConnectingActivity myActivity;`

Then in my `onCreateDialog` hook I instantiate it: 

`myActivity = (ConnectingActivity) getActivity();` how can I get to see my exceptions? LogCat is not showing me anything